# Trying to index kafka topic in Elasticsearch with Kafka Connect

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to index a topic from kafka in avro to elasticsearch format but
 I have problems with my timestamp field to be recognized by
 elasticsearch as date format field.

I have used the following configuration for the connector.

```
   {
          "name": "es-sink-barchart-10",
      "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",

        "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",

        "type.name":"type.name=kafka-connect",

        "topics": "exchange_avro_01",

        "topic.index.map": "exchange_avro_01:exchange_barchart",

        "key.ignore": "true"
     }
    }
```

The original field is bigint type and I want the target field to be date type with any valid format with elasticsearch. I have defined a dynamic template to try to solve it in the following way:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_template/kafkaconnect/" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index_patterns": "exchange*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "kafka-connect": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
    {
          "dates": {
        "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "match": "TIME",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
     ,
      "properties": {
          "CLOSE": {
            "type": "double"
          },
         .
         .
         .
        }
      }

    }
  }
}'
```

When I load the connector described above nothing is indexed to elasticsearch.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your source is a bigint then presumably it's an epoch. If it's an epoch, then this won't work:

```
"mapping": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
```

because you're telling Elasticsearch that the date format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (which it isn't).

So instead, try this (omitting your custom mapping for the moment; get this working first and then add that back in):

```
{
  "index_patterns": "exchange*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "kafka-connect": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "dates": {
            "match": "TIME",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date"
            } } } ] } } }
```

Also ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection

> nothing is indexed to elasticsearch.

Check the Kafka Connect worker log and the Elasticsearch log for any errors.

Comment: how can i check kafka connect worker log and elasticsearch log?

Comment: Info [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained) on how to check the Connect log. The log for Elasticsearch will be on the stdout if you launch it from the commandline, or in the appropriate log folder if not.

Comment: The solutions seem to be working fine but there is a huge hit in performance. Is there any other way to transform it? How about updating the schema within the schema registry?