# Kafka Elasticsearch Connector Timestamps

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I can see this has been discussed a few times [here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323383/trying-to-index-kafka-topic-in-elasticsearch-with-kafka-connect) but I think the solutions are out of date due to breaking changes in Elasticsearch.

I'm trying to convert a long/epoch field in my Json in my Kafka topic to an Elasticsearch date type which is pushed through the connector.

When I try to add a dynamic mapping, my Kafka connect updates fail because Im trying to apply two mappings to a field, _doc and kafkaconnect.  This was a breaking change around version 6 I believe where you can only have one mapping per index.

```
{
    "index_patterns": [ "depart_details" ],
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "scheduled_to_date": {
          "match":   "scheduled",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      } 
    ]
}}
```

I've now focussed on trying to translate the message at source in the connector by changing the field to a timestamp, time or date.

```
    "transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.field" : "scheduled",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp"
```

However, any messages I try to send through this transformer fail with

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Java class class java.util.Date does not have corresponding schema type.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:604)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJson(JsonConverter.java:668)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToJsonWithoutEnvelope(JsonConverter.java:574)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.fromConnectData(JsonConverter.java:324)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.getPayload(DataConverter.java:181)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.DataConverter.convertRecord(DataConverter.java:163)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.tryWriteRecord(ElasticsearchWriter.java:285)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.write(ElasticsearchWriter.java:270)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.put(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:169)
```

Seems like a really common thing to need to do, but I don't see how to get a date or time field into Elastic through this connector in version 7?

Comment: The Confluent documentation states that the ES connector [is currently not supported](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html#prerequisites) with ES 7. Can you show how your current `depart_details` mapping look like?

Comment: Goddamnit I burnt a day on this and even went hunting for compatibility.  Thanks!

Comment: It might suffice to change `type.name=_doc` (instead of `type.name=kafkaconnect`). According to [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/314) this has worked for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Confluent documentation states that the ES connector [is currently not supported](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html#prerequisites) with ES 7.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/314), it might suffice to change `type.name=kafkaconnect` to `type.name=_doc` in your connector configuration.

Comment: Had the issue for several days now, thanks a lot it works !